# Using HDIV with struts 1.2.9

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1, hdiv

Our application is using struts 1.2.9 and we would like to integrate HDIV (HTTP Data Integrity Validator) in order to enhance its security.
However, it seems that the last version of HDIV (2.1.12) is only compatible with struts 1.3.8.

Currently, we prefer to not upgrade struts 1.2.9 to 1.3.8 because it needs some work.
So what can we do to use HDIV with struts 1.2.9 ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.hdiv.org/overview.php) Community Edition only supports latest 2 minor GA releases. **Struts 1.2.9** is part of [Enterprise Edition](http://www.hdiv.org/enterprise-edition.php) product.

I paste here Enterprise Edition supported frameworks and versions copied from hdiv.org web page:

> Community Edition only supports latest 2 minor GA releases of Spring
>   MVC (3.1 & 3.2), Grails (Starting at 2.3.1), JSF and Struts 1.
>   However, Enterprise Edition supports all versions of Spring MVC,
>   Grails, JSF, Struts 1, Struts 2 and advices for custom frameworks.